Проблема обхода капчи Python
Пишу парсер, но есть проблема обхода капчи. Выдает ошибку:

ERROR relyhome.parser Failed to solve CAPTCHA

def solve_captcha(self):
    url = "https://2captcha.com/in.php"
    params = {
        'key': self.api_key,
        'method': 'userrecaptcha',
        'googlekey': self.site_key,
        'pageurl': self.page_url,
        'json': 1
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    if response.json().get('status') == 1:
        captcha_id = response.json().get('request')
        url = "https://2captcha.com/res.php"
        params = {
            'key': self.api_key,
            'action': 'get',
            'id': captcha_id,
            'json': 1
        }
        for _ in range(30):  # Ожидание решения CAPTCHA
            response = requests.get(url, params=params)
            if response.json().get('status') == 1:
                return response.json().get('request')
            time.sleep(5)
    return None

def parse(self):
    self.setup_driver()
    try:
        self.login()
        self.save_cookies()
        self.main_loop()
    finally:
        self.driver.quit()

def setup_driver(self):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def login(self):
    self.driver.get(MAIN_URL)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-email")))

    email_field = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-email")
    password_field = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-password")

    email_field.send_keys(LOGIN)
    password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)

    captcha_solution = self.solve_captcha()
    if captcha_solution:
        captcha_field = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "captcha-field")
        captcha_field.send_keys(captcha_solution)
    else:
        raise Exception("Failed to solve CAPTCHA")

    login_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
    login_button.click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DataTables_Table_0")))


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

есть подозрения что вас детектят, селениум устарел и детектится сервисами, попробуйте nodriver

проблема в том,что необходимо парсер и загрузка в google-sheets, проблема обхода капчи - Сервис распознавания, обхода и решения капчи 2Captcha, хотелось бы свой сервис написать, т.к. этот платный
